# Python : Text to ASCII & ASCII to text converter program

Tags: python, ascii

i am a newbie to python 2.7 , trying to create a simple program, which takes an input string from the user, converts all the characters into their ascii values, adds 2 to all the ascii values and then converts the new values into text. So for example, if the user input is "test" , the output should be "vguv".

This is the code i have written so far :

```
message = input("enter message to encode")

for ch in message:
     message2 = ord(ch) + 2
     print "\n\n"
     encodedmessage = ""
     for item in message2.split():
            encodedmessage += chr(int(item))

print ("encoded msg in text : "), encodedmessage
```

It doesnt seem to be working properly, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Always spend a little time trying to digest errors the interpreter throws at you.  This code would return `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'`, and show you the line that didn't work.  It fairly directly says that `message2` is an `'int' object` which you probably weren't expecting.  If you can't figure it out (some errors can be fairly obscure), *post the error* instead of just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: By the way: Nick T's advice is very sound: take the error from the interpreter and look at what it means. It should also give you a line number and some context, so you know where to look. Make sure each variable is holding that you think it's holding.

Answer (score 2):

`message2 = ord(ch) + 2` makes `message2` an integer, and so of course you cannot then call `split` on it -- it's a single int representing a single character, why ever would you want to *split* it?!  Plus, you're resetting `encodedmessage` to the empty string each time through the loop, so once you've fixed the `split` weirdness (by simply removing it!) you'll only see the last characted of course; move the `encodedmessage = ''` to **before** the loop instead.

Comment: It's bad practice to use the += operator on strings in general, isn't it? You're creating a new string each time it's called. Perhaps it would be better to keep a list of characters and then do `''.join(whateverlist)`?

Comment: Alex: it is, and I considered this as well. But I think it would confuse the OP, so it's forgiveable on this case.

Comment: @Alex Bliskovsky: Although its often repeated that `''.join()` is faster than string concatenation, I think with modern releases of Python, that is not necessarily true. In fact, in this microtest, http://paste.ubuntu.com/479529/, `python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.add_strings(1000)` takes 201us, while `python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.join_strings(1000)` takes 250us per loop. I'd be interested to hear if @Alex Martelli would weigh in on this.

Comment: Ah, it looks like @Alex Martelli has already answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349311/python-string-join-is-faster-than-but-whats-wrong-here/1350289#1350289

Comment: @Alex, yep, but I agree with @rbp -- there are clearly deeper problems here, tackling them first seems preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up characters and strings. When you loop throught a string (such as "message"), on each iteration you'll get a single character. Also, ord(ch) is an integer, a number, so you can't "split" it.

Also, don't use "input", use "raw_input" instead.

What you want is probably something similar to this:

```
message = raw_input("enter message to encode: ")
encoded_message = ""
for ch in message:
     encoded_ord = ord(ch) + 2
```

Here you don't have a new message yet, as the loop gies you one character at a time, so I'm renaming the variable to "encoded_ord", which better describes what it holds.

Now, you can turn this "encoded ord" into an encoded character, and add it to the encoded message:

```
     encoded_ch = chr(encoded_ord)
     encoded_message += chr(encoded_ch)

print "encoded msg in text:", encodedmessage
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do a `rot-13` (or generalized "`rot-x`") type function?

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

def rotx(data,rotby):
    total = []
    for char in data:
        if char in ascii_uppercase:
            index = (ascii_uppercase.find(char) + rotby) % 26
            total.append(ascii_uppercase[index])
        elif char in ascii_lowercase:
            index = (ascii_lowercase.find(char) + rotby) % 26
            total.append(ascii_lowercase[index])
        else:
            total.append(char)
    return "".join(total)
```

Running:

```
>>> import rotx
>>> rotx.rotx("test",2)
'vguv'
>>> rotx.rotx("IBM-9000",-1)
'HAL-9000'
```

If you blanket add 2 to ASCII characters, `}` becomes non-printable, `~` turns into something depending on your character encoding