# Implementing sum() for custom datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading, custom-data-type

As I understand it, for it to be possible to cast `sum()` on an object, it must be an iterable, and must be "addable", i.e. it must implement methods `__iter__` and `__add__`. However, when I do this for my class `Point` (just an example), this doesn't work.

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.x, self.y))


print(Point(2, 2) + Point(1, 1))
>>> (3, 3)    # As expected; good!

points = [Point(0, 0), Point(2, 0), Point(0, 2), Point(2, 2)]
print(sum(points))    # Expect (4, 4)
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Point'
```

---

If I implement `__radd__` the same as `__add__` I then get an attribute error when I try `sum()`:

```py
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Based on the errors my `Points` are somewhere being separated to just `ints` but I'm not sure where.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that `sum` is not required to work for non-numeric types. It's not entirely clear, though, what `sum` will consider a numeric type. (For example, it works for `list`s, but explicitly rejects `str`s.)

Comment: Isn't that just because `''.join()` is a better alternative for string concatenation than `sum()`? Edit, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525359/python-sum-why-not-strings)

Comment: It absolutely is, though I'm not entirely sure why `sum` can't be implemented to call `join` itself, rather than raise an exception.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, a few others on the above thread agree too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because `sum` starts with a default value of `int` and when doing `sum(points)` what really is happening is `sum` is first trying to add `0 + Point(0, 0)` and hence the error. If you check the help on `sum`, this will become pretty evident,

> Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:
>
> sum(iterable, start=0, /)
>       Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
>
> ```
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
> This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
> reject non-numeric types.
> ```

Change the line from,

```
>>> print(sum(points))
```

to

```
>>> print(sum(points, Point(0, 0)))
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I wonder why `sum(sequence)` was chosen to start from 0 rather than just add the elements left to right (or right to left). Maybe to handle cases where `len(sequence) <= 1`.

Comment: I am not too sure why the implementation chose that. I'd have to check : )

Comment: `0` is just the default starting value, both to handle empty sequences and the normal use of simply summing the values. You can pass a different starting value if you like. `sum(values, x) == x + sum(values)`. For example, `sum([[1], [2]], [3]) == [3] + sum([[1], [2]], []) == [3, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Yeah, make sense to have the starting value as 0. It's easier to have a starting value, and since usually the iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.