# TypeError when applying sum to a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
print(sum(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

This line of code gives
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.`
In my understanding, it's equivalent to "a" + "b" + "c", so why is this happening?

Comment: The specific error you're seeing is because `sum` has a `start` argument that's the base all the other values are added to, and it defaults to `0`, which clearly can't be added to a `str`. Passing `""` as `start` will raise a different exception, because using `sum` in this way is a form of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm), and they special-cased it to reject that usage; you're supposed to use `"".join(["a", "b", "c"])` which is much more efficient.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you very much!!   How can I choose your answer as the best one?

Comment: This link is also very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525359/python-sum-why-not-strings