# Why `s = [x for x in "hello"]; sum(s)` doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a list of characters that I want to make a string out of. I can add them like this:

```py
In [1]: s = [x for x in "hello"]

In [2]: s[0] + s[1] + s[2] + s[3] + s[4]    # Works
Out[2]: 'hello'
```

But adding via `sum()` doesn't work. This surprised me, because in my mental model, `sum()` should just reduce each element in the list via `+`.

```py
In [3]: sum(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a1d2094b79e8> in <module>
----> 1 sum(s)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Nor can I call `str()` on a list of characters:

```py
In [4]: str(s)
Out[4]: "['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']"
```

For comparison, in Julia I can do

```
julia> s = [x for x in "hello"]
5-element Array{Char,1}:
 'h': ASCII/Unicode U+0068 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'e': ASCII/Unicode U+0065 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'l': ASCII/Unicode U+006C (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'l': ASCII/Unicode U+006C (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 'o': ASCII/Unicode U+006F (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)

julia> prod(s)
"hello"

julia> String(s)
"hello"
```

(Note that string concatenation is done by taking products instead of sums in Julia.)

I include the comparison because if anything, I would expect this to *work* in Python and *fail* in Julia, since Julia actually distinguishes between string and character data types. The Julia variable `s` is an array of `Char`s while the Python variable `s` is a list of `str`s.

I assume the reason this works in Julia is "because someone enabled it to," so my question is instead about Python:

- **Why does the `sum()` call fail to concatenate strings in Python?**
- **Why does the error message claim that Python is trying to add an `int` to a `str`? Where is the `int`?**

Please note that **I am not asking** about how to concatenate a list of strings (which can be done using `"".join()`).

Comment: `sum()` has an implicit start value of `0`. It also actively refuses to work on strings if you change the start value because concentrating strings this way is inefficient.

Comment: You could set initial value with sum(s, ''), but it is actively refused in favor of join. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525359/python-sum-why-not-strings