# Strings and the and operator: best practice, differences with +

Tags: python

For one of my sites, I need to check if several class attributes are defined and not empty. So far, I've happily used `if self.attr:`, which in my mind is the shorthand for `if self.attr is not None and self.attr is not '':`, or whatever the undefined value of the attribute is.

This works fine, but yields to surprising behavior when checking multiple string attributes. `'' and ''` is not `False` (as I expected), but `''`.

This begs the question: are there other types for which the `and` operator does not force a typecast to `bool`? 
I can't come up with an example where this difference in behavior would cause an actual different outcome for the `if`-clause (after all, `''` still evaluates to `False`), but am left with the gut feeling that there's edge cases that could be a trap.

Lastly, I'd be keen to know if anybody knows why it was implemented that way? I thought the Zen of Python encourages one way and one way only, and the `+` operator already seems to bethe intuitive way for string concatenation.

Comment: The answers don't seem to cover this, focusing on the boolean part of the question, but `and` never does string concatenation; it's not like `+` at all.

Comment: [Use `''.join` to concatenate strings, not `+`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349311/python-string-join-is-faster-than-but-whats-wrong-here/1350289#1350289)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`and` never typecasts to bool. Rather, `if` calls `bool()` on the result of expressions.

An expression using `and` (and `or`, for that matter), short-circuits when it can determine that the expression will not evaluate to True or False based on the first operand, and returns the last evaluated value:

```
>>> 0 and 'string'
0
>>> 1 and 'string'
'string'
>>> 'string' or 10
'string'
>>> '' or 10
10
```

This 'side-effect' is often used in python code. Note that `not` *does* return a boolean value. See the [python documentation on boolean operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) for the details.

The documentation also explains what constitutes a `True` or `False` equivalent for various types, such as `None`, `0`, `''` and empty containers being `False`, while most everything else is equivalent to `True`.

For custom classes, you need to define the [`.__nonzero__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) (returns `True` or `False`) or a [`.__len__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (returns an int, where `0` is `False` and everything else is `True`), to influence their boolean equivalent, otherwise they'll always default to `True`.