# reading multiple csv file into a big pandas data frame by appending the columns of different size

Tags: python, csv, pandas

so i am creating some data frame in a loop and save them as a csv file. The data frame have the same columns but different length. i would like to be able to concatenate these data frames into a single data frame that has all the columns something like

`df1
    A  B C
0   0  1 2
1   0  1 0
2  1.2 1 1
3   2  1 2`

`df2
    A  B C
0   0  1 2
1   0  1 0
2  0.2 1 2`

`df3
    A  B C
0   0  1 2
1   0  1 0
2  1.2 1 1
3   2  1 4
4   1  2 2
5  2.3 3 0`

i would like to get something like

`df_big
    A  B  C   A  B C  A  B  C 
0   0  1  2   0  1 2  0  1  2
1   0  1  0   0  1 0  0  1  0
2  1.2 1  1  0.2 1 2 1.2 1  1
3   2  1  2           2  1  4
4                     1  2  2
5                    2.3 3  0`
is this something that can be done in pandas?

Comment: Er.. have you looked at [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects):

```
df_big = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

yields

```
     A   B   C    A   B   C    A  B  C
0  0.0   1   2  0.0   1   2  0.0  1  2
1  0.0   1   0  0.0   1   0  0.0  1  0
2  1.2   1   1  0.2   1   2  1.2  1  1
3  2.0   1   2  NaN NaN NaN  2.0  1  4
4  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  1.0  2  2
5  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN  2.3  3  0
```

Comment: it is in a loop so technically i dont have df1, df2...but i can create them and save them before hands. or it there a way to concatenant on fly? thank you that was fast.

Comment: Save all the DataFrames in a list and then call `pd.concat(list_of_dfs)` once to create `df_big`.

Comment: Concatenating inside the loop is inefficient because each call to `pd.concat` requires allocation of a new chunk of memory and copying the data from the pieces into the resultant DataFrame. It is the same reason why [string concatenation should be done with `str.join` rather than using `s += ...` in a loop.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349311/python-string-join-is-faster-than-but-whats-wrong-here/1350289#1350289).