# What makes python's itertools.groupby so fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, python-itertools

I am evaluating successive terms of the look and say sequence (more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

I used two approaches and timed them both. In the first approach, I just iterated over each term to construct the next one. In the second, I used `itertools.groupby()` to do the same. The time difference is pretty dramatic, so I made a figure for fun:

[image: graph]

What makes `itertools.groupby()` so efficient? The code for the two approaches is below:

1st approach:

```
def find_block(seq):
    block = [seq[0]]
    seq.pop(0)

    while seq and seq[0] == block[0]:
        block.append(seq[0])
        seq.pop(0)

    return block

old = list('1113222113')
new = []
version1_time = []

for i in range(40):
    start = time.time()
    while old:
        block = find_block(old)
        new.append(str(len(block)))
        new.append(block[0])
    old, new = new, []
    end = time.time()
    version1_time.append(end-start)
```

2nd approach:

```
seq = '1113222113'
version2_time = []

def lookandread(seq):
    new = ''
    for value, group in itertools.groupby(seq):
        new += '{}{}'.format(len(list(group)), value)
    return new

for i in range(40):
    start = time.time()
    seq = lookandread(seq)
    end = time.time()
    version2_time.append(end-start)
```

Comment: As a side note, you should not benchmark manually like this; use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). The docs for `time` even explain why. It may not be relevant here (although there are _some_ questions where the whole answer turns out to be "your benchmarks are wrong", it's certainly not always the case), but it's better to do the right thing than to do the wrong thing and hope it doesn't matter this time.

Comment: Your first approach is written in a way that incredibly waste resources. It creates lists and pops elements all the time!! Maybe rewrite it using a set and generator functions, it will be closer to what `groupby()` does

Comment: Please read `groupby`'s implementation-equivalent python code: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby , which costs just O(n), while your implementation costs O(n^2).

Comment: @PaulRooney That isn't really relevant here. Implementing something in C can't change quadratic time into constant time; all it can do is reduce the constant factor. I'd be willing to be that if you just If you copy and paste the pure-Python "rough equivalent" `groupby` out of the `itertools` docs, it's somewhere between 1% and 1000% slower, but it retains the constant growth of the C implementation.

Comment: @PaulRooney The reason they're both N^2 faster than the OP's manual solution is that the OP does work per iteration that's quadratic on the size (popping N elements off the front of a list one by one, etc.), as nosklo explained, while `groupby` does constant work per iteration, so one is O(N^2M) while the other is just O(M).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I changed my code and dropped all instances of `list.pop()` and now it runs pretty fast too. @abarnert, after your suggestion I read about the `timeit` module and the problems it solves (quantization errors, other system processes), and I would like to use it. However, my problem is that `timeit` does not return the values computed while running the code, and I need each term of the sequence to generate the next one. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Take a look at [gojomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130288/gojomo)' response as edited by [Nicholas Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6372/nicholas-riley) to the StackOverflow question [How to measure elapsed time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python).. This response provides a mechanism using a context manager which would allow passing parameters of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the groupby solution isn't fast, your other solution is slow.

Because the slow one doesn't properly iterate the `old` sequence but deconstructs it one digit at a time with `seq.pop(0)`. That takes Θ(`len(seq)`) time for each pop, and Θ(n^2) time for the whole `while old` loop, where n is its initial length before that loop.

The groupby solution instead does the same in [somewhere between Θ(n) and Θ(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44487537/12671057) time (depends on the Python implementation and the memory allocator), due to the repeated concatenation of strings. You probably used CPython, which has an optimization that mostly makes it linear. You can guarantee linear time by using a result *list* instead of a string.

Also, n grows exponentially by ~30% each of the 40 rounds (print the lengths or see the Wikipedia article). So with the quadratic algorithm, round i takes roughly Θ((1.3^i)^2) = Θ(1.69^i) time. That grows fast. Although it's odd how *very* long it took for you. For the last round (i=39), your plot shows 175 seconds, while I need only 5 seconds.