# Time complexity of algorithm which merges a stack of linked lists

Tags: merge, stack, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to find the complexity (in big O notation) of the following pseudocode, in terms of k and n.

`d` is a stack of size n, and each element in the stack is a linked list of length k. The `merge` function runs in O(a + b) time where a and b are the lengths of the two linked lists it is merging.

```
while d.size >= 2
    L = d.pop()       // O(1) 
    L1 = d.pop()      // O(1)
    L2 = merge(L, L1) // O(a + b)
    d.push(L2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity is O(kn<sup>2</sup>), where n is the size of the original stack. To see why, think about the lengths of the lists that are merged; the result of the previous merge is always on top of the stack, so it is always one of the lists which is merged next:

- The first merge is of length k + k = 2k.
- The next merge is of length 2k + k = 3k.
- The next merge is of length 3k + k = 4k.
- ...
- The final merge is of length (n-1)k + k = nk.

The running times of the merge operations are proportional to the lengths of the resulting lists after merging, so we can add those up:

> 2k + 3k + 4k + ... + nk = k × (2 + 3 + ... + n) = k × ((n<sup>2</sup> + n)/2 - 1)

Discarding the dominated terms and the constant factor of 1/2 gives O(kn<sup>2</sup>). Note that the sizes of the computations actually *increase* as the loop continues; on later iterations, more data is being merged, not less.

---

For intuition, you should expect the time to be quadratic in the number of lists for the same reason that naively concatenating strings together takes [quadratic time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487537/why-does-naive-string-concatenation-become-quadratic-above-a-certain-length) in the number of strings.

As an aside, if you use a queue instead of a stack then this takes O(kn log n) time instead. I'll leave you with that to think about!