# What is the most efficient way to concatenate two strings and remove everything before the first ',' in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, concatenation

In Python, I have a string which is a comma separated list of values. e.g. '5,2,7,8,3,4'

I need to add a new value onto the end and remove the first value,

e.g.
 '5,22,7,814,3,4' -> '22,7,814,3,4,1'

Currently, I do this as follows:

```
mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4'
latestValue='1'
mylist = mystr.split(',')
mystr = ''
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
   if i==0:
      mystr += mylist[i+1]
   if i>0:
      mystr += ','+mylist[i+1]

mystr += ','+latestValue
```

This runs millions of times in my code and I've identified it as a bottleneck, so I'm keen to optimize it to make it run faster.

What is the most efficient to do this (in terms of runtime)?

Comment: Why are you storing the list as a string instead of a list?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use a string as I'm fetching the string from a database and then reinserting the new string.

Comment: If this is truly your bottleneck then you may have run across the rare application where you really would benefit from rewriting in another language.  In any language with mutable strings you could keep appending `,latestValue` and offsetting the pointer to the start, only really copying every Nth time (based on how long a string buffer you choose).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the solutions! Very impressive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_, sep, rest = mystr.partition(",")
mystr = rest + sep + latestValue
```

It *also* works without any changes if `mystr` is empty or a single item (without comma after it) due to [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) returns empty `sep` if there is no `sep` in `mystr`.

You could use `mystr.rstrip(",")` before calling `partition()` if there might be a trailing comma in the `mystr`.

Comment: Very nice! If you *don't* have to handle the degenerate cases, this similar one-liner would work `mystr = ','.join([mystr.partition(",")[2],latestValue])`.

Comment: @martineau, `','.join()` is much less efficient than `mystr.partition(",")[2]+","+latestValue`

Comment: @gnibbler: I don't see any difference in CPython (`.join()` is slower in jython, pypy)

Comment: @gnibbler: You're quite right. Somewhere along the line I was brainwashed into almost always avoiding string concatenation via '+' (and especially '+=') in my Python code -- and have fallen into the habit of doing so. Do you know of anything definitive on the subject (other than `timeit` tests ;-)?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: In timing tests I just ran with CPython 2.7, '+' was faster by nearly an order of magnitude (10x) when comparing `'a'+','+'b'` to `','.join(['a','b'])`.

Comment: @martineau, string concatenation has been improved in the (fairly common) case where there is only one reference to the string. See PyString_ConcatAndDel in http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Yes they are, as it is with statistics. FWIW if I change the pair generator to `yield 'a'*i, 'bb'` in your benchmark, which I think is closer to what the OP might encounter, '+' is about 33% faster. That's a far cry from 10x, but still significant enough to consider when something will be done millions of times in code you're is trying to optimize. All of this has little to do with your answer which uses '+' and is clearly the best one because of its speed and elegant handling of the special cases.

Comment: This is still 10% slower than my answer (at least for strings of the size given in the question)

Comment: @martineau: I've tried `'a'*i, `bb` variant the difference is `~5 %` not `33 %`.

Comment: @J.F. timeit as per my answer. The extra time is taken by binding+looking up the extra variables

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Using a combination of the `cProfile` and `pstats` modules on 10 trials, I got an average percentage difference of the cumulative time in each method (`join_join` and `join_plus`) of slightly less than 7%, and a ratio of the two of ~1.32, which is why I said about 33% faster.

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
if mystr == '':
    mystr = latestValue
else:
    mystr = mystr[mystr.find(",")+1:] + "," + latestValue
```

This should be much faster than any solution which splits the list. It only finds the first occurrence of `,` and "removes" the beginning of the string. Also, if the list is empty, then `mystr` will be just `latestValue` (insignificant overhead added by this) -- thanks Paulo Scardine for pointing that out.

Comment: +1. I think this answer has finally sunk the fact that strings have a 'find' method into my skull.

Comment: The best so far: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.625 usec per loop

Comment: @Paulo Scardine no it does not (at least not in my python 2.6). If there is no `,` in the string, it returns -1. Adding 1 to that results in 0, the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: the complete solution would be 'mystr=mystr[mystr.find(",")+1:]+","+latestValue', which results ',1' if mystr is empty.

Comment: 'mystr+=","+latestValue; mystr=mystr[mystr.find(",")+1:]' is slightly worst but is the better performer so far.

Answer (score 6):

```
mystr = mystr.partition(",")[2]+","+latestValue
```

improvement suggested by Paulo to work if mystr has < 2 elements.
In the case of 0 elements, it does extend mystr to hold one element.

```
_,_,mystr = (mystr+','+latestValue).partition(',')

$ python -m timeit -s "mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4';latestValue='1'" "mystr[mystr.find(',')+1:]+','+latestValue"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.847 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4';latestValue='1'" "mystr = mystr.partition(',')[2]+','+latestValue"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.703 usec per loop
```

Comment: +1 This is the fastest by a longshot and I did not know about `partition`.

Comment: this code doesn't work for `len(mystr.split(",")) < 2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111711/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-two-strings-and-remove-everything-b/4112208#4112208

Comment: Seems to work for len(mystr.split(",")) != 1, and works if you add the last element before: 'mystr+=','+latest; mystr = mystr.partition(",")[2]'

Comment: @Paulo, and it can be made almost as fast by using tuple unpacking instead of indexing.

Answer (score 4):

**best version**: [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111711/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-two-strings-and-remove-everything-b/4112015#4112015)

---

Since you need speed (millions of times is a lot), I profiled. This one is about twice as fast as splitting the list:

```
i = 0
while 1:
    if mystr[i] == ',': break
    i += 1
mystr = mystr[i+1:] + ', ' + latest_value
```

It assumes that there is one space after each comma. If that's a problem, you can use:

```
i = 0
while 1:
    if mystr[i] == ',': break
    i += 1
mystr = mystr[i+1:].strip() + ', ' + latest_value
```

which is only slightly slower than the original but much more robust. It's really up to you to decide how much speed you need to squeeze out of it. They both assume that there will be a comma in the string and will raise an `IndexError` if one fails to appear. The safe version is:

```
i = 0
while 1:
    try:
        if mystr[i] == ',': break
    except IndexError:
        i = -1
        break
    i += 1
mystr = mystr[i+1:].strip() + ', ' + latest_value
```

Again, this is still significantly faster than than splitting the string but does add robustness at the cost of speed.

---

Here's the timeit results. You can see that the fourth method is noticeably faster than the third (most robust) method, but slightly slower than the first two methods. It's the fastest of the two robust solutions though so unless you are sure that your strings will have commas in them (i.e. it would already be considered an error if they didn't) then I would use it anyway.

$ python -mtimeit -s'from strings import tests, method1' 'method1(tests[0], "10")' 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'from strings import tests, method2' 'method2(tests[0], "10")' 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'from strings import tests, method3' 'method3(tests[0], "10")' 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'from strings import tests, method4' 'method4(tests[0], "10")' 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 usec per loop

---

$ python -mtimeit -s'from strings import tests, method5' 'method5(tests[0], "10")' 
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 usec per loop

This is [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111711/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-two-strings-and-remove-everything-b/4112015#4112015)

Comment: could you add a test using `partition()` to your suite?

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = mystr.split(',')
mylist.append(latestValue);
mystr = ",".join(mylist[1:])
```

String concatenation in python isn't very efficient (since strings are immutable).  It's easier to work with them as lists (and more efficient).  Basically in your code you are copying your string over and over again each time you concatenate to it.

Comment: Don't forget that he also needs to remove the head of the list. What he really needs is a queue: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

Comment: For further reading about performance of string vs. list concatenation, please take a look at ["What is the most efficient string concatenation method in python?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316887/what-is-the-most-efficient-string-concatenation-method-in-python).

Comment: I remove the head of the list by using mylist[1:] in the join statement

Comment: I'm actually surprised that there's a difference between them.  Perhaps the added step of converting the latestValue to a list before concatenating the lists is slower than a straight up append.

Comment: @GWW: right in the nail, "mystr=','.join(mystr.split(',')[1:])+','+latestValue" performs the same.

Comment: @Paulo, I saw that I just don't understand why, it's not like our solutions are buggy and non-functional.

Comment: For the record, all three of my solutions beat this one in terms of speed. It's hardly the second best. Two of them beat the best answer for speed as well.

Comment: @aaronsterling:  I like your answer especially with the comparisons.

Comment: list has no advantage over string in this application as removing the first element is O(n) for the list

Comment: If you look at my code I didn't remove the first element from the list.  I used mylist[1:], which behaves as a generator.  It's still faster than copying a string over and over again.  However, may not be as fast as other solutions.

Comment: @GWW, `mylist[1:]` makes a new list by doing a shallow copy of the items of `mylist`. A generator version could use `itertools.islice`

Answer (score 2):

Edited:
Not the best, but I love one-liners. :-)

```
mystr = ','.join(mystr.split(',')[1:]+[latestValue])
```

Before testing I would bet it would perform better.

```
> python -m timeit "mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4'" "latestValue='1'" \
"mylist = mystr.split(',')" "mylist.append(latestValue);" \
"mystr = ','.join(mylist[1:])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 usec per loop
> python -m timeit "mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4'" "latestValue='1'"\
"','.join(mystr.split(',')[1:]+[latestValue])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 usec per loop
> python -m timeit "mystr = '5,22,7,814,3,4'" "latestValue='1'"\
'mystr=mystr[mystr.find(",")+1:]+","+latestValue'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.625 usec per loop
```