# Remove extra characters in the string in Python

Tags: python, string, strip

I have couple of strings (each string is a set of words) which has special characters in them. I know using strip() function, we can remove all occurrences of only one specific character from any string. Now, I would like to remove set of special characters (include !@#%&*()[]{}/?<> ) etc.

What is the best way you can get these unwanted characters removed from the strings.

in-str  = "@John, It's a fantastic #week-end%, How *about* () you"

out-str = "John, It's a fantastic week-end, How about you"

Comment: The ` () ` will be particularly difficult to get rid of without regular expressions.

Comment: May I ask **why** you want to do this? In particular, if you want to prevent code injection attacks, you might prefer to _escape_ special characters rather than remove them. How that would go would depend on the specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string

s = "@John, It's a fantastic #week-end%, How about () you"
for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>":
    s = string.replace(s, c, "")

print s
```

prints "John, It's a fantastic week-end, How about  you"

Answer (score 1):

The `strip` function removes only leading and trailing characters.
For your purpose I would use python `set` to store your characters, iterate over your input string and create new string from characters not present in the `set`. According to other stackoverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/good-way-to-append-to-a-string) this should be efficient. At the end, just remove double spaces by clever `" ".join(output_string.split())` construction.

```
char_set = set("!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>")
input_string = "@John, It's a fantastic #week-end%, How about () you"
output_string = ""

for i in range(0, len(input_string)):
    if not input_string[i] in char_set:
        output_string += input_string[i]

output_string = " ".join(output_string.split())
print output_string
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
import re

foo = 'a..!b...c???d;;'
chars = [',', '!', '.', ';', '?']

print re.sub('[%s]' % ''.join(chars), '', foo)
```

I presume that this is what you wanted.

Comment: Btw, I recommend building the array of chars which are not accepted by a foreach loop, or in a similar way to ensure dynamic editing of the restricted chars.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
s = "@John, It's a fantastic #week-end%, How about () you"
chars = "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>"
s_no_chars = "".join([k for k in s if k not in chars])
s_no_chars_spaces = " ".join([ d for d in "".join([k for k in s if k not in chars]).split(" ") if d])
```