# how do I modify a url that I pick at random in python

Tags: python, flask

I have an app that will show images from reddit. Some images come like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKuXA.jpg, when I need to make them look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfiH1.jpg. Just add an (i) at the beginning and (.jpg) at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do what you need. I expanded on @jh314's response and made the code a little less compact and checked that the url *started* with `http://imgur.com` as that code would cause issues with other URLs, like the google search I included. It also only replaces the first instance, which could causes issues.

```
def fixImgurLinks(url):
    if url.lower().startswith("http://imgur.com"):
        url = url.replace("http://imgur", "http://i.imgur",1) # Only replace the first instance.
        if not url.endswith(".jpg"):
            url +=".jpg"
    return url

for u in ["http://imgur.com/Cuv9oau","http://www.google.com/search?q=http://imgur"]:
    print fixImgurLinks(u)
```

Gives:

```
>>> http://i.imgur.com/Cuv9oau.jpg
>>> http://www.google.com/search?q=http://imgur
```

Comment: Thanks every one, I ended up using this version. Sometimes I still get page load errors because there is no image, I click on the url and it says page not found or something different. Is there a way to add a check for the image and if its not found, than skip it

Comment: That URL has an extra `/` at the end, so it is an invalid URL. You can check the URL is valid during transformation, but you'd be better the ask a new question for that.

Comment: thanks I added code to remove it and so far its been working!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a string replace:

```
s = "http://imgur.com/Cuv9oau"
s = s.replace("//imgur", "//i.imgur")+(".jpg" if not s.endswith(".jpg") else "")
```

This sets s to:

```
'http://i.imgur.com/Cuv9oau.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Python's regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to place the `i`.  As for the `.jpg` you can just [append it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/good-way-to-append-to-a-string).