# How to encrypt strings in python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this function.
def encrypt(msg, code):
    '''(str, str) -> str
    Return msg encrypted using the given code.  The code
    is an ordering of the alphabet plus the space and '.' 
    characters. The position of each character in the code
    string gives the index of the replacement character in 
    the regular alphabet 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .'

```
In the first example below, 'h' is in position 20, so we 
select the letter in position 20 in the alphabet, or 'u'.

>>> encrypt('hello there', '. zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba')
'uxqqnbiuxkx'
>>> encrypt('hello there', '. zaybxcwdveuftgshriqjpkolnm')
'rlzzyborlsl'
'''
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
i = 0
for char in len(msg[i]):
    if msg[i] == code and msg[i] == alpha[i]:
        return msg
```

I have that, but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: What is this condition for:   `if msg[i] == code and msg[i] == alpha[i]:`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def encrypt(msg, code):
    coded_msg = '' 
    for char in msg:
        coded_msg += alpha[code.index(char)]
    return coded_msg

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. '
print( encrypt('hello there', '. zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba') )
```

Comment: Why did you put the alpha before the def function? shouldn't it be after the docstring?

Comment: There is no particular reason for that in this case. In my test code I put it after and it works. Just make sure for it to be seen by the encrypt function. Maybe put it in your main or in worst case in `encrypt()` itself.

Comment: Also, what does the coded_msg += line mean? like what is it essentially saying?

Comment: coded_msg is the encrypted message (output), which is a string here and I am adding the (encrypted) chars to it. You can pass the encypted chars to your msg varriable directly but that would require you to be careful about the indexes.

Comment: @dg123 I added some test code, to help you understand it better.

Comment: what does += mean specifically?

Comment: @dg123 It is an incrementation of char's elements into the string. You started with `coded_msg= ''` as an empty string and now each iteration you add the extracted char from alpha to it. 

`coded_msg += alpha[code.index(char)]` 
is equal to 
`coded_msg  = coded_msg + alpha[code.index(char)]`

Check this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/good-way-to-append-to-a-string

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks

Comment: Wait, it says index out of range now, when I test it

Comment: What input throws out this error? and did you add some code? I re-tested the function and it works. Be careful not to give inputs with characters that are not included in `alpha` or in `code` such as capital letters or numbers because those are not handled by the function.

Comment: Ok, I see where I might've went wrong now. It might be because I forgot to add the period and space after the alphabet.

Comment: If the code answers your question please accept it as an answer.

Comment: yes, it does, thanks

Comment: @dg123 By accept I mean click the green tick icon on the left side of my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is the same thing as:

```
coded_msg = coded_msg + alpha[code.index(char)]
```