# What is the right way to add sections to an existing string

Tags: python

I'm now to python and I wanted to know the correct way of doing this. I'm trying to add pieces to make a full string but I get symbols in the string output

```
def responseLibrary(days, hours, minutes, seconds):
global globalSeconds
response = globalSeconds, " seconds equals "

if days > 0:
    response += days, " days "
if hours > 0:
    response += hours, " hours "
if minutes > 0:
    response += minutes, " minutes "
if seconds > 0:
    response += seconds, " seconds "
return response
```

The output I get looks like this

```
(10, ' seconds equals ', 10, ' seconds ')
```

Comment: Use `+` to combine the strings, not `,`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I append one string to another in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, you could use

```
return ''.join(map(str, response))
```

What's happening is that when you say `response = globalSeconds, " seconds equals "` You're creating a **tuple**. When you use the print function, you're **not passing in a single string** created by some sort of comma-based joining operation. You're passing in multiple arguments, and the print function handles them appropriately.

If you wanted to join strings all the way through, the `+` operator allows for string concatenation. It is typically more efficient to use `.join()` rather than a large number of concatenations however.

For reference, this answer uses the builtin `str.join()` method, [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). It also uses the `map()` builtin [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). What they're doing is basically as follows:

1. By the end of your program, `response` is a **tuple** of different values.
2. Not all of those values are strings (notice that you never converted any integers to a different type).
3. The builtin `.join()` method requires an iterable of strings for its input.
4. The line `map(str, response)` is roughly the same as `(str(x) for x in response)`. Now we have an iterable object of string representations of the values we want to join together.
5. The `.join()` method takes all of those strings and concatenates them into one giant string like you want.
6. Note the `''` at the beginning of `.join()`. That's the separator we're using between each of the strings we're joining. You could just as easily use spaces or commas or anything else like `', '.join(...)`.

Comment: This worked what is the documentation for this? That way I can fully understand what it's doing.

Comment: Sure thing. One sec.

Comment: @DRodriguez There you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join strings and ints with a comma.  That gives you a tuple, as your output shows.

You need to convert the ints to strings.   One way is: `response += str(seconds) + " seconds"`

Another way would be to use the string format function:  `response += "{} seconds".format(seconds)`