# Python function return multiple elements

Tags: python, string, function, email, return

I have the function below :

```
    def fisap(self):
    print("*" * 42)
    print("Nrc", "Data".rjust(10), "Intrari".rjust(13), "Iesiri".rjust(12))
    print("*" * 42)
    for elem in self.ddop.keys():
        if elem in self.ddint.keys():
            print(str(elem), str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10), str(self.ddint[elem]).rjust(13))
        else:
            print(str(elem), str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10), str(0).rjust(13), str(self.ddies[elem]).rjust(12))
    print("*" * 42)
    print("Soldul final este de : " + str(self.sold))
```

It returns the following when called ( example ) :
[image]

It returns what it need to return, all good here, but my question is how i can store all this return text, in this format, in a variable, string or anything else to can send it by email using smtplib. If i try to send the email using the message body of : selfitem.fisap() it sends None .
Like this :
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to store the data in a variable instead of only printing it to the console. Then return that variable and use it as content for your email. Right now the function doesn't return anything which is why it displays `None`.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python) on how to append strings.

Comment: Thanks, it works in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the whole message in a string before printing it, only then you can return it using `return`

`print` is not the same as `return`

```
def fisap(self):
    elements = []
    for elem in self.ddop.keys():
        if elem in self.ddint.keys():
            elements.append(str(elem), str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10), str(self.ddint[elem]).rjust(13))
        else:
            elements.append(str(elem), str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10), str(0).rjust(13), str(self.ddies[elem]).rjust(12))

    message = "{divider}\n{headers}\n{elements}\n{divider}\n{total}".format(
        divider="*" * 42,
        headers='\t'.join(["Nrc", "Data".rjust(10), "Intrari".rjust(13), "Iesiri".rjust(12)]),
        elements=elements,
        total="Soldul final este de : " + str(self.sold)
        )

    print(message)
    return message

def main():
    returned_value = fisap() #fisap() is called and its result is stored in the variable returned_value
    print(returned_value) #we can then print it again or treat it as we would a string variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !
Based on your solution, i`ve wrote the following code and it worked :

```
    def trimitefisaemail(self):
    a = ("*" * 42) + "\n"
    b = "Nrc" + "Data".rjust(10) + "Intrari".rjust(13) + "Iesiri".rjust(12) + "\n"
    c = []
    for elem in self.ddop.keys():
        if elem in self.ddint.keys():
            c.append(str(elem) + str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10) + str(self.ddint[elem]).rjust(13))
        else:
            c.append(str(elem) + str(self.ddop[elem]).rjust(10) + str(0).rjust(13) + str(self.ddies[elem]).rjust(12))
    cc = "\n".join(c)
    d = "\n" + "Soldul final este de : " + str(self.sold)
    message = "%s%s%s%s\n%s%s"%(a,b,a,cc,a,d)
    sendemailfunction(message)
```