# my code puts out invalid syntax but i dont know whats wrong with my variable

Tags: python, variables, input

it puts out invalid syntax but I defined x so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong

I have tried putting x as an int and float. because it has to be a number otherwise it won't work

```
x=input("adja meg az x magasságát, szélességét egy szám ként")
szokoz=" "
slash="/"
backslash="\\"
print(slash x*szokoz backslash)
```

invalid syntax

Comment: are you trying to multiply two strings together? what is the expected output?

Comment: try ```print(slash, x*szokoz, backslash)```

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  If you want to convert to an integer, wrap the call inside `int()`, like this: `x = int(input("type an integer"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I append one string to another in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python)

Comment: for anyone wondering about what i want to do with this i want it to spell out a big x that you define the height of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't concatenate strings simply by putting them next to each other, you need to use the concatenation operator (you can put string *literals* next to each other, but that's just part of the literal syntax).

Also, if you're using Python 3, `input()` returns a string, not a number, you need to convert it to an integer.

```
x=int(input("adja meg az x magasságát, szélességét egy szám ként"))
szokoz=" "
slash="/"
backslash="\\"
print(slash + x*szokoz + backslash)
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised, python is ok with multiplying a `string` by an `int` and adding the result to other strings.

Comment: @tgikal You can multiply any sequence by an int, and it just duplicates the sequence that many times. E.g. `[0] * 3 == [0, 0, 0]`

Comment: It makes sense: x * 3 == x + x + x. When `+` is concatenation, it simply concatenates that many times.

Comment: how do I do that properly? i have tried x=int(x) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @hetothe What do you get instead of the expected number?

Comment: @Barmar oh sorry didn't notice it thankyou for the help!