# Python not writing whole output into file

Tags: python

I am trying to join every_line in a txt file with a header text. But after successfully joining 
up the lines. I cannot seem to write the file correctly as it will only write the last joined line into the `internallinks.txt`. How can I make it to write the whole output of `combined` into the file?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much!

**Python code**

```
with open(r"C:\Users\xingj\Desktop\writing.txt") as f:
    internallink = ("www.icom.org.cn")
    for every_line in f:
        combined = (internallink + every_line.strip())
        out_str = "".join(combined)


with open("C:\\Users\\xingj\\internallinks.txt",'w') as b:
    b.write(out_str)
```

**Content of writing.txt**

```
/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1122
/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1125
/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=586&
/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1126
/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=470&
```

**Output of internallinks.txt**

```
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=470&
```

**Output of command `print (combined)` before `with` is closed**

```
PS C:\Users\xingj> & python c:/Users/xingj/testingagain.py
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1122
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1125
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=586&
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1126
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=470&
PS C:\Users\xingj>
```

Comment: You are reassigning the string in each iteration, not appending to it. `out_str = "".join(combined)`

Comment: I see. Thank for replying! Sorry I'm just a newbie coder. How can I fix this?

Comment: [How do i append one string to another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'd like a nested approach:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\xingj\Desktop\writing.txt") as f, open("C:\\Users\\xingj\\internallinks.txt",'w') as b:
    for line in f:
        b.write('www.icom.org.cn'+line)
```

Comment: I don't consider this a "clean" approach.  The output of any given input line doesn't depend on any other input line, so reading the whole file into memory makes no sense.  It should read one line, modify it, and write out that line.  Repeat until input EOF.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, you are re-assigning the `out_str` variable to the current value of `combined`. Instead, for your desired output, you should be appending the new value ,i.e. `combined` to `out_str`.
Just replace

```
for every_line in f:
    combined = (internallink + every_line.strip())
    out_str = "".join(combined)
```

with

```
for every_line in f:
    combined = (internallink + every_line.strip())
    out_str = out_str + combined
```

and your code should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new string to the combined variable you have to add the old with assigned combined to assign all of the strings

```
internallink = "www.icom.org.cn"
combined = ''
for every_line in tt:
    # If you don't want the text on newline you can remove `\n`
    combined = combined + internallink + every_line.strip() + '\n' 

print(combined)
```

OutPut:-

```
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1122
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1125
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=586
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1126
www.icom.org.cn/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=470
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with input files, I recommend you assume the source is extremely large and code accordingly.  For example, dealing with it line by line and not reading the entire file into memory:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\xingj\Desktop\writing.txt") as input_file:
    with open(r"C:\Users\xingj\internallinks.txt", 'w') as output_file:
        for link in input_file:
            output_file.write('www.icom.org.cn' + link)
```

You can combine both `open()` statements into one `with` statement, but I see no advantage into doing so.  If there is one, please comment!