# concatenate two index value of a list into a single index value in python list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Let, a list

```
name=["new","text","test"]
```

now, I want to concatenate the first two index values of the list name and make a single index value

```
new_name=["new text"]
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
name=["new","text","test"]
new_name=' '.join(name[:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_name = [ name[0]+ ' ' +name[1] ]
```