# How do I format a string using a dictionary in python-3.x?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-3.x

I am a big fan of using dictionaries to format strings. It helps me read the string format I am using as well as let me take advantage of existing dictionaries. For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = 'Title'

a = MyClass()
print 'The title is %(title)s' % a.__dict__

path = '/path/to/a/file'
print 'You put your file here: %(path)s' % locals()
```

However I cannot figure out the python 3.x syntax for doing the same (or if that is even possible). I would like to do the following

```
# Fails, KeyError 'latitude'
geopoint = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}
print '{latitude} {longitude}'.format(geopoint)

# Succeeds
print '{latitude} {longitude}'.format(latitude=41.123,longitude=71.091)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since the question is specific to Python 3, here's using [the new f-string syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), available since Python 3.6:

```
>>> geopoint = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}
>>> print(f'{geopoint["latitude"]} {geopoint["longitude"]}')
41.123 71.091
```

Note the outer single quotes and inner double quotes (you could also do it the other way around).

Answer (score 510):

Is this good for you?

```
geopoint = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}
print('{latitude} {longitude}'.format(**geopoint))
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked. But I don't understand the use of the 'pointer notation'. I know Python doesn't use pointers, is this an example of kwargs?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli That is a format parameter (Minimum field width), not a pointer to a pointer C++ style. http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Comment: Python 3.2 introduced [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map). _Similar to `str.format(**mapping)`, except that `mapping` is used directly and not copied to a `dict`. This is useful if for example `mapping` is a dict subclass_

Comment: @eugene What does ** do to a python dictionary? I don't think that it creates an object because print(**geopoint) fails giving syntax error

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal it spreads the dictionary with the name=value pairs as individual arguments i.e. `print(**geopoint)` is same as `print(longitude=71.091, latitude=41.123)`. In many languages, it is known as *splat operator*. In JavaScript, it's called *spread operator*. In python, there is no particular name given to this operator.

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal new to me too. it's pretty [cool](https://repl.it/@SamyBencherif/BoldMoccasinOperation).

Answer (score 88):

To unpack a dictionary into keyword arguments, use `**`. Also,, new-style formatting supports referring to attributes of objects and items of mappings:

```
'{0[latitude]} {0[longitude]}'.format(geopoint)
'The title is {0.title}s'.format(a) # the a from your first example
```

Comment: I find this answer better, as adding the positional index for the placeholder makes the code more explicit, and easier to use. Especially if one has something like this:
`'{0[latitude]} {1[latitude]} {0[longitude]} {1[longitude]}'.format(geopoint0, geopoint1)`

Comment: This is useful if you're using a `defaultdict` and don't have all the keys

Answer (score 88):

As Python 3.0 and 3.1 are EOL'ed and no one uses them, you can and should use [`str.format_map(mapping)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) (Python 3.2+):

> Similar to `str.format(**mapping)`, **except that mapping is used directly and not copied to a `dict`**. This is useful if for example mapping is a `dict` subclass.

What this means is that you can use for example a `defaultdict` that would set (and return) a default value for keys that are missing:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> vals = defaultdict(lambda: '<unset>', {'bar': 'baz'})
>>> 'foo is {foo} and bar is {bar}'.format_map(vals)
'foo is <unset> and bar is baz'
```

Even if the mapping provided is a `dict`, not a subclass, this would probably still be slightly faster.

The difference is not big though, given

```
>>> d = dict(foo='x', bar='y', baz='z')
```

then

```
>>> 'foo is {foo}, bar is {bar} and baz is {baz}'.format_map(d)
```

is about 10 ns (2 %) faster than

```
>>> 'foo is {foo}, bar is {bar} and baz is {baz}'.format(**d)
```

on my Python 3.4.3. The difference would probably be larger as more keys are in the dictionary, and

---

Note that the format language is much more flexible than that though; they can contain indexed expressions, attribute accesses and so on, so you *can* format a whole object, or 2 of them:

```
>>> p1 = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}
>>> p2 = {'latitude':56.456,'longitude':23.456}
>>> '{0[latitude]} {0[longitude]} - {1[latitude]} {1[longitude]}'.format(p1, p2)
'41.123 71.091 - 56.456 23.456'
```

---

Starting from 3.6 you can use the interpolated strings too:

```
>>> f'lat:{p1["latitude"]} lng:{p1["longitude"]}'
'lat:41.123 lng:71.091'
```

You just need to remember to use the *other* quote characters within the nested quotes. Another upside of this approach is that it is much faster than [calling a formatting method.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362140/918959)

Comment: Nice one, Is there any performance improvements over `format`? (Given that it is not copied to a dict)

Comment: @BhargavRao not much, 2 % :D

Comment: @BhargavRao if you're looking for performance, use this `'%(latitude)s %(longitude)s'%geopoint` ;)

Answer (score 41):

```
print("{latitude} {longitude}".format(**geopoint))
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why this doesn't have more votes.

Comment: This is the simplest option, TBH.  It's also the similar way as you transform a list to varargs. This should be the way.

Answer (score 7):

The Python 2 syntax works in Python 3 as well:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.title = 'Title'
... 
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> print('The title is %(title)s' % a.__dict__)
The title is Title
>>> 
>>> path = '/path/to/a/file'
>>> print('You put your file here: %(path)s' % locals())
You put your file here: /path/to/a/file
```

Comment: plus it's also noticably more performant than `f""` or `"".format()` ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use format_map to do what you want

```
print('{latitude} {longitude}'.format_map(geopoint))
```

This has the advantage that

- the dictionary does not have to be blown up into parameters (compared to `**geopoint`) and that
- the format string only has access to the provided map and not the entire scope of variables (compared to F-strings).

Answer (score 4):

```
geopoint = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}

# working examples.
print(f'{geopoint["latitude"]} {geopoint["longitude"]}') # from above answer
print('{geopoint[latitude]} {geopoint[longitude]}'.format(geopoint=geopoint)) # alternate for format method  (including dict name in string).
print('%(latitude)s %(longitude)s'%geopoint) # thanks @tcll
```

Comment: you missed one ;) `print('%(latitude)s %(longitude)s'%geopoint)` this is also significantly faster than the other 2

Comment: @tcll  Actually I wanted the examples, where I can use the dictionary name inside the string. Something like this `'%(geopoint["latitude"])s %(geopoint["longitude"])s'%{"geopoint":geopoint}`

Answer (score 2):

Most answers formatted only the values of the dict.

If you want to **also format the key** into the string you can use *dict.items()*:

```
geopoint = {'latitude':41.123,'longitude':71.091}
print("{} {}".format(*geopoint.items()))
```

Output:

> ('latitude', 41.123) ('longitude', 71.091)

If you want to format in an arbitry way, that is, not showing the key-values like tuples:

```
from functools import reduce
print("{} is {} and {} is {}".format(*reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), [list(item) for item in geopoint.items()])))
```

Output:

> latitude is 41.123 and longitude is 71.091

Comment: note there's a chance 'longitude' could come before 'latitude' from `geopoint.items()` ;)