# Python 3.2: How to pass a dictionary into str.format()

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, string-formatting, keyword-argument

I've been reading the Python 3.2 docs about string formatting but it hasn't really helped me with this particular problem.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
stats = { 'copied': 5, 'skipped': 14 }
print( 'Copied: {copied}, Skipped: {skipped}'.format( stats ) )
```

The above code will not work because the format() call is not reading the dictionary values and using those in place of my format placeholders. How can I modify my code to work with my dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This does the job:

```
stats = { 'copied': 5, 'skipped': 14 }
print( 'Copied: {copied}, Skipped: {skipped}'.format( **stats ) )  #use ** to "unpack" a dictionary
```

For more info please refer to:

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-examples
  and
- http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Why did this one get less up-votes? It has more information (links to docs) and a better example.

Answer (score 16):

you want `.format(**stats)` as that makes stats part of format's kwargs.