# Getting a key error while using a dict with TEMPLATE.format()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

At a loss on this.  I'm getting a key error but I can't figure out why as the key referenced looks like it's in the dict.

Any help?

```
TEMPLATE = "{ticker:6s}:{shares:3d} x {price:8.2f} = {value:8.2f}"

report = []

stock = {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'price': 128.75, 'value': 2575.0, 'shares': 20}

report.append(TEMPLATE.format(stock))
```

This is the error I got:

```
    report.append(TEMPLATE.format(stock))
KeyError: 'ticker'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `**` in front of the dictionary argument. So, your last line would be:

```
report.append(TEMPLATE.format(**stock))
```

and it should work.

So your code should be:

```
TEMPLATE = "{ticker:6s}:{shares:3d} x {price:8.2f} = {value:8.2f}"

report = []

stock = {'ticker': 'AAPL', 'price': 128.75, 'value': 2575.0, 'shares': 20}

report.append(TEMPLATE.format(**stock))
```

Related: [Python 3.2: How to pass a dictionary into str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487501/python-3-2-how-to-pass-a-dictionary-into-str-format)