# How can we give multiple arguments to .format() from a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

How can we give arguments in a string containing `'{}'`? Example: `string = "my age is '{}' years old'`. We can print output by -> `print(string.format(23))` so, output will be as -> `my age is 23 years old`.

I'm quessing is that when we have multiple `'{}'` in a string we have to send multiple arguments to `'{}'` the arguments are in a list or a tuple like `(1, 2,3)`. How can we apply `.format()` to this?

I have this doubt while solving this problem -> question: `I am 12 years 3 months 8 days old` to required output: `I am 3 years 8 months 12 days old`. (Numbers should be in sorted form).

Comment: `'i have {} fingers, {} nose, and {} arms'.format(*(1,2,3))`

Comment: @wwii: That's overly complicated. This is simpler: `'i have {} fingers, {} nose, and {} arms'.format(1,2,3)`

Comment: [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: @martineau - They were asking how to use a tuple with str.format, at least that's how I read it.

Comment: @wwii: You're right, my mistake — sorry.

Comment: Related: [How to pass a dictionary into str.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487501/python-3-2-how-to-pass-a-dictionary-into-str-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
string = "I am {} years {} months {} days old".format((12),(3),(8))
```

OR

```py
string = "I am {} years {} months {} days old".format(*(12,3,8))
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Alternatively `"I am {y} years {m} months {d} days old".format(y=12, m=3, d=8)` or `"I am {y} years {m} months {d} days old".format(**{'y':12, 'm':3, 'd':8})`.