# Dynamic fields in a Python string

Tags: python

So, I'm writing a small backup solution that loads some configuration settings from a YAML file. I would like to allow the user to set a naming scheme for the generated backup. Something like:

`{database_name} @ {host} {month}_{year}`

And allow them to freely choose fields from a set. The first thing that comes to my mind while thinking about how to convert this to a final string, is using the string's `format` method.

The code would then check for every possible field and if it exists, format the string accordingly. I wonder, however if there is a more pythonic way to go about this than just looping through the string, checking for every possible field and replacing the value.

Comment: Why would it need to 'check every possible field'? Usually templates (including format-from-dictionary) parse out the fields to replace following a set of rules.

Comment: Because the user could use one or more fields from a set

Comment: maybe `grep` the used fields and replace them?

Comment: How does that differ from (eg.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x?

Comment: Because I don't know beforehand which fields I will have to replace.

Comment: And if I just throw a dictionary with all of the possibilities, I will get an error

Comment: @FBidu: so? the template doesn't have to use all of the fields you provide.

Comment: really? I thought so... Gonna check it out

Comment: Anyway, if wishing to do this manually (ie. not using str.format or another template library for whatever reason), a regular-expression-with-replacement-function would be a decent minimal approach: it allows performing a custom action for each matched token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a dictionary `fields` with all the fields you want to support, and apply that dictionary using the `**keywords` call syntax:

```
filename = template.format(**fields)
```

The template can use as many or as few of those fields as it requires.

Demo:

```
>>> fields = {'foo': 'The Foo value', 'bar': 'A barren area', 'spam': 'The greatest canned meat!', 'eggs': 'scrambled or easy over?'}
>>> template = 'Please provide me with eggs, {eggs}'
>>> template.format(**fields)
'Please provide me with eggs, scrambled or easy over?'
```

In this sample, the template only uses the `egg` field, the other available names are not used but are available for other templates.

If you do ever need to list all field names, use a [`string.Formatter()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to parse out the fields:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> list(Formatter().parse('{foo} {bar:042d}'))
[('', 'foo', '', None), (' ', 'bar', '042d', None)]
```

The [`Formatter.parse()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) yields `(literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion)` tuples.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I really thought this would give me an error for throwing arguments that won't necessarily be used. Thank you

Comment: @FBidu: always test your hypotheses! Note that neither the [`str.format()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) nor the [format string syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) state that all arguments must be used.

Comment: yeah, I was really reckless jumping to that conclusion. Thanks for the thorough answer :D