# Format dictionary to take value

Tags: python

I have a member variable;

```
valid_add_customer_request = {
    "client": {0},
    "name": "CustomerName",
    "account_number": "W/L141123512",
    "mobile_number": "1232 414122",
    "landline_number": "1234515123",
    "email": "CustomerName@email.com"
}
```

Where the client is an id of another object. Ideally I'd like to do something like but because the variable is a dictionary this isn't possible.

```
valid_add_customer_request.format(1)
```

Is there a clean way of achieving the above.

Comment: Please restate your question. The value of `"client"` is a set

Comment: This may help https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update. 
`valid_add_customer_request.update(dict(client=1))`

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x) or the opposite?

Comment: Exactly what @MohammadAlbakri posted is what I was looking for, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: in the example data value of 'client' is set, whar @MohammadAlbakri code does is to make it int. Also, no need to do update, just `valid_add_customer_request['client'] = 1` or {1} to preserve the set type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one of the following, depending what desired outcome is:

```
valid_add_customer_request['client'] = 1 # client = 1 i.e. int
valid_add_customer_request['client'] = {1} # client = {1} i.e. set with one element 1
valid_add_customer_request.setdefault('client', set()).add(1) # client = {0,1}, i.e. add element to the existing set
```

Comment: I went with valid_add_customer_request['client'] = 1 in the end, thanks for your help!

Comment: you know what you want it to be. just make sure it doesn't break you code elsewhere if it expects `client` to be `set` as in example.

Comment: I'm only really using this in unit tests at the minute, so it changes for every request. Definitely a good thing to know I can do this though.

Answer (score 2):

```
valid_add_customer_request = lambda x: {
    "client": x,
    "name": "CustomerName",
    "account_number": "W/L141123512",
    "mobile_number": "1232 414122",
    "landline_number": "1234515123",
    "email": "CustomerName@email.com"
}

valid_add_customer_request(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update.

`valid_add_customer_request.update(dict(client=1))`

Comment: Links to external websites may be invalid in the future. It is recommended to explain the solution in the answer to avoid this.