# How to print a returned dictionary output from a function inside a string(a sentence) in python? (Processing)

Tags: python, processing, jython

I'm creating a program that calculates the total cost of a meal by taking the following inputs:
meal_cost,tax_rate,tip_rate,number_eating

and printing them inside a string with a function call. I looked up on StackOverflow, but could not find a question that suited my situation (printing a dictionary returned from a function in a string)

I have a single function that takes all the inputs and returns a dictionary output. I want to print those returned values in a string with a function call, all in the same line. This is what I tried:

```
def calculatedCost(meal_cost,tax_rate,tip_rate,number_eating):
  tax = round(float(meal_cost * tax_rate) / 100,2)
  tip = round(float(meal_cost * tip_rate) / 100,2)
  total_cost = round(meal_cost + tax + tip,2)
  division = round(total_cost / number_eating,2)
  return {'tax': tax, 'tip': tip, 'total_cost':total_cost, 'division':division} 

print("The cost of your meal is: {total_cost}, the tax on your meal is: {tax}, the tip is equal to: {tip}, and the split total is: {division}".format(calculatedCost(62.75,5,20,2)))
```

and I get this error: (I'm using Processing)

```
KeyError: total_cost
processing.app.SketchException: KeyError: total_cost
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.convertPythonSketchError(SketchRunner.java:240)
at jycessing.mode.run.SketchRunner.lambda$2(SketchRunner.java:119)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Err, you wouldn't get Java errors in CPython. Is this Jython?

Comment: yes, its Jython.

Comment: Please ensure you tag as such in future. If you hadn't put the traceback in, we would not have known and there could be all sorts of differences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a string using a dictionary in python-3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

Comment: @roganjosh I forgot the tag, but I wrote Processing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to unpack the `dict` (note the double asterisk):

```
print("The cost of your meal is: {total_cost}, the tax on your meal is: {tax}, the tip is equal to: {tip}, and the split total is: {division}".format(**calculatedCost(62.75,5,20,2)))
```