# Python http delete requests with URL path variable

Tags: python, python-requests, path-variables

I have an Http endpoint exposed as http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{id} for delete, while making this API delete call I have to replace with the proper id

I tried below way using the requests module of python

```
param = {
  "id" : 1
}

requests.delete(url = http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{id}, params=param)
```

This API call is breaking with the error

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you meant `requests.delete(url=f"http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{id}", params=param)`? If by id you meant the parameters id the it would probably be `requests.delete(url=f"http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{param['id']}", params=param)`

Comment: @Filip, the way you are telling i need to change my endpoint url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can't run as-is. You need to quote your url string:

`url = "http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{id}"`

Reading the [docs for requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.delete), the `params` only sends the dictionary `param` as the query string, so it'll only tack on `?id=1` to the end of the URL.

What you want is the `{id}` to get the value from the dictionary. You can look at this answer for various ways: [How do I format a string using a dictionary in python-3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

You want something like

`requests.delete(url = "http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/qc/{id}".format(**param))`

Comment: Correct, params way could work for ?id= but my request has a placeholder in the url.
by looking at the solution, given in the link provided by @Foo L, it looks like only replacing placeholder is the way, but i just wanted to know does requests methods have any direct way of doing this

Comment: deserves more upvotes