# parsing LaTex in matplotlib from string

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I want some special characters in my title I can do something like the following. `plt.title(r'$\lambda$')` However, I would like to use a dict which helps pick between different strings. So I was wondering if it is possible to parse those?

e.g.

```
a = '$\lambda$'
plt.title(r a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a string using a dictionary in python-3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

Comment: in your example `plt.title(a)` would suffice. Can you maybe expand it to show what your usecase would be. Maybe in a more elaborate title?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Oh damn, I didn't check to see if that worked... Ok problem solved.