# How can I call .format() from a dictionary when I can only access the string values of that dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a program where the user uploads a JSON file and then the program turns it into a dictionary and then does some math on it. Before that math I want to access items of the dictionary within the actual dictionary. Essentially this would be a popup message that says something along the lines of "The values uploaded from the JSON file are x, y, and z".

```
   example_dict = {
        "first_item": 11,
        "second_item": "this is a sentence",
        "message_item": "'Second item was {}, and the first item is {}'.format(example_dict['second_item'], example_dict['first_item])"
    }

print(example_dict)
```

I already have the uploading from a JSON part working, this is an example of what I would like to have happen.

Yes I am aware that I can update the dictionary values from outside of it, but, at the end, I have to rewrite the dictionary back to the JSON file, so I am essentially then hard coding it. Whatever is in that dictionary is rewritten. For example I could do,

```
message = "Second item was {}, and the first item is {}".format(example_dict['second_item'], example_dict['first_item'])
example_dict['message_item'] = message
```

This the means that, if the user wants to edit the JSON file to have it only show the first value, they cannot do that.

Comment: You can't do this in the dictionary itself. It sounds like you're looking for some kind of template system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eval or exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python) functions in python to execute arbitrary python code.

```
example_dict = {
        "first_item": 11,
        "second_item": "this is a sentence",
        "message_item": "'Second item was {}, and the first item is {}'.format(example_dict['second_item'], example_dict['first_item])"
    }

message = eval(example_dict['message_item'])
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my desired output using the `.format(**dictionary)` method. I found it in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x) and was able to tweak it to make it work for my specific use case. Working code below.

```
example_dict = {
    "first_item": 11,
    "second_item": "this is a sentence",
    "message_item": "Second item was {second_item}, and the first item is {first_item}"
}


message = example_dict['message_item'].format(**example_dict)
print(message)
```