# Fast concatenation of bytes() in python3

Tags: python, list, byte

I have an array of byte-strings in python3 (it's an audio chunks).
I want to make one big byte-string from it. Simple implementation is kind of slow. How to do it better?

```
chunks = []
while not audio.ends():
  chunks.append( bytes(audio.next_buffer()) )
  do_some_chunk_processing()

all_audio=b''
for ch in chunks:
  all_audio += ch
```

How to do it faster?

Comment: Do you mean to run the processing on each loop?

Comment: Are you sure that piecing together the chunks is what's taking the time?  Your main `while` loop looks like it has the potential of being very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach you could try and measure would be to use `bytes.join`:

```
all_audio = b''.join(chunks)
```

The reason this might be faster is that this does a pre-pass over the chunks to find out how big `all_audio` needs to be, allocates exactly the right size once, then concatenates it in one go.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join)

Answer (score 7):

Use `bytearray()`

```py
from time import time

c = b'\x02\x03\x05\x07' * 500 # test data

# Method-1 with bytes-string

bytes_string = b''

st = time()
for _ in range(10**4):
    bytes_string += c

print("string concat -> took {} sec".format(time()-st))

# Method-2 with bytes-array

bytes_arr = bytearray()

st = time()
for _ in range(10**4):
    bytes_arr.extend(c)
# convert byte_arr to bytes_string via
bytes_string = bytes(bytes_arr)

print("bytearray extend/concat -> took {} sec".format(time()-st))
```

benchmark in my Win10|Corei7-7th Gen shows:

```
string concat -> took 67.27699875831604 sec
bytearray extend/concat -> took 0.08975911140441895 sec
```

the code is pretty self-explanatory. instead of using `string+=next_block`, use `bytearray.extend(next_block)`. After building `bytearray` you can use `bytes(bytearray)` to get the bytes-string.

Comment: Finally a fast solution, I was adding >50,000 chunks of bytes on the fly and I got a 140x speed up by using `bytearray`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `fstring`

```
all_audio = b''
for ch in chunks:
        all_audio = f'{all_audio}{ch}'
```

Which seems to be faster for small strings, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316887/what-is-the-most-efficient-string-concatenation-method-in-python) comparison.