# Return a list from a for loop python

Tags: python

I want to combine inputs into a for loop in python and return the relevant dates. My code is as follows:

```
years =['2020', '2021'] 
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']

for YearItem in years:
    for item in months:
        vars1 = ('01 ' + item + ' ' + YearItem,)
    print(vars1)
```

My output currently returns ('01 MAR 2021') but I want it to return ('01 JAN 2020','01 FEB 2020',...,'01 MAR 2021')

Comment: You are looking for ``itertools.product``: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

### The problem

```
for YearItem in years:
        for item in months:
            # variable 'vars1' is assigned a new tuple in every iteration.
            # 1. iteration: vars1 = ('01 JAN 2020')
            # 2. iteration: vars1 = ('01 FEB 2020')
            # last iteration: vars1 = ('01 MAR 2021')
            vars1 = ('01 ' + item + ' ' + YearItem,)
        print(vars1)
```

The problem with your implementation is that you assign a new tuple containing a single element (which is a string that you concatenate) to the variable `vars1` in every single iteration. Secondly, it appears you put the print() within the first loop but not the second, which - I assume - is also not what you want. Be careful with [indentation](https://www.scaler.com/topics/python/indentation-in-python/) in Python as it can cause all kinds of problems ;)

### The solution

What you want is a **single list** which contains **all** the concatenated strings. There are many ways to do this with some solutions being preferred over others (see section below).

#### "Non-pythonic"

```py
years =['2020', '2021']
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']

# create a new empty list
vars1 = list()
# iterate over all years and months
for year in years:
    for month in months:
        # append a new element (= concatenated string) to the list created before
        vars1.append('01 ' + month + ' ' + year)
# print the whole list (notice that print() is not indented!)
print(vars1)
```

This solution will work but it is not "pythonic" and it also is rather slow and difficult to read. While the performance gain by using f-Strings instead of simple string concatenation will most likely be irrelevant for your program you should still consider using them instead as it is much more concise. So you should replace `vars1.append('01 ' + month + ' ' + year)` with `vars1.append(f'01 {month} {year}')`.

#### "Pythonic"

```py
from itertools import product

years =['2020', '2021']
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']

vars1 = [f'01 {month} {year}' for year, month in product(years, months)]
print(vars1)
```

Solution as provided by [Torben Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221166/torben-klein) [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71395335/17487348).

This, to me, is the most concise, straightforward and clear solution which also is "pythonic" and therefore the best solution for the given problem.

This approach uses a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Note that this solution should also be the fastest in terms of string concatenation according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362140/17487348).

## A few pointers

I assume you are new to Python development so I wanted to extend on some of the answers already given. While all of them are correct (in both syntax and semantic) there are a few things you should consider in order to write better Python code or when you're evaluating answers you get on StackOverflow.

#### Code style

There are general guidelines on how Python code should be written concerning its style with the most fundamental concepts being stated in the [Zen of Python](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).
Another key term is in this area is **"pythonic code"**, which you may want to read on in [this blog](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html), this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean) or for a very practical approach with samples and **Dos and Don'ts** have a look at [A Hitchhiker's guide to Python - Code Style](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/#).
Also note some of the conventions described in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). One of them stating that you should not use CamelCase to name your variables so applying this you would need to rename your variable `YearItem` to `year_item` or better yet `year`.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Bc with each months loop you overwrite the previous one. Try making a list so you have the desired format.
Something like this?

```
years =['2020', '2021'] 
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']
final_list = []
for YearItem in years:
    for item in months:
        final_list.append('01 ' + item + ' ' + YearItem)
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
['01 JAN 2020', '01 FEB 2020', '01 MAR 2020', '01 JAN 2021', '01 FEB 2021', '01 MAR 2021']
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am quite new to python so instead of using double brackets, I tried to append without double brackets before and got an error.

Comment: @Yusuf You actually dont need the double brackets, for me its works both ways

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
vars = [f'01 {month} {year}' for year, month in product(years, months)]
```

See here [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a list return of vars1?

```
years =['2020', '2021'] 
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']

list1 = []
for YearItem in years:
    for item in months:
        vars1 = ('01 ' + item + ' ' + YearItem,)
        list1.append(vars1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only variation I would add to this for conciseness only:

```
years =['2020', '2021'] 
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR']

list1 = []

for YearItem, item in zip(years, months):
    vars1 = ('01 ' + item + ' ' + YearItem)
    list1.append(vars1)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.