# Trying to make a list that is ['_', '_', '_'] with the length depending on a for loop

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list of 'blanks' that can be filled in individually later. The length of the list is dependent on a value (`currentWord`) which is why I can't hard-code it.

```
iter8 = len(currentWord)
for i in currentWord:
    answerListNEW.append(' ')
    #
for i in currentWord:
    answerListNEW[i] = '_'
```

I get errors that the index must be integer, not str. Is there a way for the program to accept the 'blank space' ?
For simplicity, lets say currentWord = 'alpha' so that it's simple and there's just 5 iterations.

SECONDLY,
I would also like to print that list as a concatenated string so it's just
'_____'. (That way when values are added it becomes '**v**' and such.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.Where the code says `for i in currentWord:`, what values do you expect `i` to have each time through the loop? Why? Did you try to check what the values are? Have you tried following a Python tutorial in order to understand such fundamentals?

Comment: I also don't understand the approach to the problem. Instead of adding spaces to the (initially empty) list and then replacing them with underscores, why not just add underscores to the list instead?

Comment: I suggest adding `print(i)` to see what `i` is. You might even need to do `print('*', i, '*')

Comment: `answerListNEW = [' '] * len(currentWord)` (or `['_'] * len(currentWord)` to get the end result directly)? That said, presizing is frowned upon (it's usually less performant than just calling `.append` on demand), so it's rare you want to do it.

Comment: What is the `iter8` variable for? Did you consider using that?

Comment: Why not just something like `answerListNew = ['_'] * len(currentWord)`?

Comment: As for joining, that's just [`''.join(list_of_strings)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1316887/364696).

Comment: `list('_' * len(currentWord))`

Comment: @PeterWood: Typically more efficient to make the template of the final type (`[' ']` or `list('_')` as you prefer) first, *then* multiply. Multiplying first, then converting, means you need two huge sequences, and you have to read the entirety of the temporary sequence to initialize the final one (making `str`'s iterator keep recreating the `'_'` object over and over when `list` could have directly copied a single pointer to the expanded `list` and directly applied all `len(currentWord)` refcnt increments in a single bulk operation).

Comment: The efficiency of multiplying first gets truly horrible when you're using a character outside of whatever your implementation's singleton cached character limit is (for CPython, it's Latin-1, caching all len `1` strings with `ord` values below 256). Because the `str` iterator will make *new* objects for each of those `len` one `str`s, and now you're storing `len(currentWord)` separate instances (on 64 bit CPython, with `chr(256)` as the template, you'd go from `8 * len(currentWord)` bytes of overhead per item to `84 * len(currentWord)` bytes of overhead).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't know about implementation details.

Comment: @PeterWood: The second comment is all implementation details. But the first comment (aside from the refcnt update note that is CPython specific) is not an implementation detail; you'd have the same problem on all existing interpreters. You'd need a ridiculously sophisticated and flexible optimizer to fix that pattern (while still falling back to the slow version when `list` is replaced or the integer you're multiplying by isn't a true `int` or the like). Python is too dynamic for that. In short, it's a general rule, not specific to implementation details; convert first, then multiply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i in currentWord` will iterate over letters of that string (assuming it is a string). As the error says, lists cannot be indexed by letters.

You can use `range()`

```
answerListNEW = ['_' for _ in range(len(currentWord))]
```

Or list multiplication

```
answerListNEW = ['_'] * len(currentWord)
```

Or "listing" a string of all underscores

```
answerListNEW = list('_' * len(currentWord))
```

> also like to print that list as a concatenated string

```
print(''.join(answerListNEW))
```

Comment: `answerListNEW = ['_' for _ in currentWord]` or `['_'] * len(currentWord)` are probably cleaner.

Comment: @norok2: Yeah, if you use a normal `for` loop, you need the indices, but if you're going to switch to a listcomp anyway, you won't be using them so no need to generate them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the standard way to generate indices is using [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: @PeterWood: I'm aware. Not sure how that's relevant here though? The moment you don't need indices, don't make 'em; doesn't matter if you can more efficiently/Pythonically generate things you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to print that list as a concatenated string so it's just '_____'

A string has most of the same properties as a list already, so why bother making the list, only to convert it to a string.

You can just do something like

```
answerListNew = '_' * len(currentWord)
```

if you want a string the same length as `currentWord` containing all '_' characters.

For an actual list of letters (allowing you to modify the letters one by one), you can do

```
answerListNew = ['_'] * len(currentWord)
```

and convert it to string form with

```
answerStrNew = ''.join(answerListNew)
```

Comment: I think they want to be able to gradually add letters.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, for the length of the string you're going to be using in a hangman game, just generating a new string each time you fill in a blank isn't going to be a significant memory problem.

Comment: @PeterWood, they're still going to have to generate a new string from each new list of letters in order to print it out...

Comment: @ThePhoton where are you going to store the guesser's progress?